# Needing help replacing a regular switch to a ceiling fan with a dimmer switch

Tags: dimmer-switch

I'm trying to install a Leviton #6674 slide dimmer with switch replacing a standard switch. After I pulled the switch plate off I found that there is 1 black, 1 white and 1 red to the old switch as in the picture. And that is all that is in the wall box. Not what I was expecting, but the house was built in 1965. This is the only switch to the light as far as I know. On the new switch I have the green ground, red, and another red labeled as the 3 way switch wire and a black wire. Will installing this be possible without changing a lot of wiring? How would I go about wiring this? Thanks for any help on this!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can we have a better photo looking into the back of the box please?  It sounds like it's time for a 3-way-switch scavenger hunt....

Comment: Is the ceiling fan controlled separately from the light? How?

Comment: Are the two screws on the other side brass colored?

Comment: @Harper I can not find any other switch that controls this fan, the screws don't appear brass colored.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Pictures added

Comment: I also have a mystery switch, which seems to control nothing at all, the pic with 2 red tabs. This living room was a garage when the house was built I believe.

Comment: Does the mystery switch do anything when the switch you're looking to replace flipped to the other position?

Comment: Ar there any legends or markings on the switch body to indicate which wires are travelers and which is the common?

Comment: No on the mystery switch, have been wondering what it was since I bought the house 2 years ago, found an old baseboard heater stored in the garage, thinking maybe it was for it at one time. I do not see any markings on the switch.